# Alpine js filterPosts is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, filter, alpine.js

Im building a WP post filter based of https://joeyfarruggio.com/wordpress/posts-category-filter/

Ive gotten though the lesson but can not solve the final bug, im getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: posts is not defined
> at [Alpine] posts (eval at  (cdn.min.js:5:665), :3:32)
> at cdn.min.js:5:1068
> at fr (cdn.min.js:1:6642)
> at cdn.min.js:5:30943
> at r (cdn.min.js:5:16370)
> at Object.Zr [as effect] (cdn.min.js:5:16158)
> at N (cdn.min.js:1:398)
> at cdn.min.js:1:511
> at Function. (cdn.min.js:5:30936)
> at r (cdn.min.js:5:2273) [Alpine] posts @ VM3507:3 (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 fr @ cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 r @
> cdn.min.js:5 Zr @ cdn.min.js:5 N @ cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @
> cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 r @ cdn.min.js:5 n @
> cdn.min.js:5 ir @ cdn.min.js:5 S @ cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @
> cdn.min.js:1 Jt @ cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 setTimeout
> (async) te @ cdn.min.js:5 (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 Promise.catch
> (async) (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 fr @ cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @
> cdn.min.js:5 r @ cdn.min.js:5 Zr @ cdn.min.js:5 N @ cdn.min.js:1
> (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 r @ cdn.min.js:5
> n @ cdn.min.js:5 ir @ cdn.min.js:5 S @ cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @
> cdn.min.js:1 Jt @ cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 cdn.min.js:1
> Alpine Expression Error: filterPosts is not defined
>
> Expression: "filterPosts(834)"
>
> <button @click=​"filterPosts(834)​" class=​"text-xl text-slate-800
> w-full text-left">​ Security Operations Platform​​ te @
> cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 Promise.catch (async)
> (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 fr @ cdn.min.js:1 (anonymous) @
> cdn.min.js:5 o @ cdn.min.js:5 (anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5 (anonymous) @
> cdn.min.js:5

```
<?php /* Template Name: test */  ?>
<html>
<head>
     <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
     <script>
    Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
      posts: "",
      limit: 10,
      category: null,
      showDefault: true,
      showFiltered: false,
    
      filterPosts(id) {
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.fetchPosts();
      },
    
      fetchPosts() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
        formData.append("offset", this.offset);
        formData.append("limit", this.limit);
    
        if (this.category) {
          formData.append("category", this.category);
        }
    
        fetch(adminURL, {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) => {
            this.posts = res.posts;
          });
      },
    }));
    
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 x-data="{ message: 'I ❤️ Alpine' }" x-text="message"></h1>
    
    <div 
    class="flex items-start gap-8 alignwide mt-32"
    x-data="filterPosts('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>')">
   <!-- Category Filter Sidebar -->
<aside class="w-1/4">
    <p class="text-xl font-medium">Categories</p>
    <?php 
        $categories = get_categories();
        if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) : 
    ?>
    <ul class="list-none px-0">
        <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) :
        
        // Skip "Uncategorized" category
        if ($category->name == 'Uncategorized') continue; ?>    

           <li :class="category == <?php echo $category->term_id; ?> ? 'bg-slate-100' : ''"
    class="hover:bg-slate-100 my-1 px-4 py-2 -ml-4 rounded-md">
    <button 
        @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"
        class="text-xl text-slate-800 w-full text-left">
            <?= esc_html( $category->name ); ?></button>
</li>
        
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</aside>

  <!-- Posts Column -->
<div class="w-3/4">
    <!-- Default posts query -->
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
        <?php 
        $query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($query_args);

if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
      ?>
      <div>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'm-0' ) );
    }?>
    <p class="text-xl font-medium mt-2"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
</div>
      <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Filtered posts -->
  <div x-show.important="showFiltered" class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6" x-html="posts"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<div x-show.important="filterPosts" class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6" x-html="posts"` must be `<div x-show.important="showFiltered" class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6" x-html="posts"></div>` the *filterPosts()* function is already called in the `@click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"`. You have also the rows : `window.Alpine = Alpine;` and `Alpine.start();` tha shouldn't be necessary. Before `</body>` there is an extra closing `</div>`

Comment: unfortunately still getting the error, will keep trying. thank you

Comment: Ive updated my scripts and run all on one page, still no luck